# how to process a file exactly once

Tags: concurrency, consumer, producer

My Java application reads data from directory and puts into a common shared resource queue, the consumer will consume the event validate the event and save it into database, i want to process the files in the directory only once even if the application restarted it should not process the file again rather start from file from where it had stopped, can anyone help me out with this

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you've tried?  Please Take the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code that we could look at? That way we can see exactly what you need.

And with what you have you might want to look into how the program can "save progress". You might be able to do something there.